# Display results of OWASP Dependency-Check Maven plugin in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, owasp

To scan the dependencies of my project for known security vulnerabilities, I'm running the [`org.owasp:dependency-check-maven`](http://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/index.html) Maven plugin as part of a Jenkins pipeline build.

The plugin happily creates the report as XML in `${project.build.directory}/security-reports`, and now I'd like to have it show up in the Test Results section of my pipeline build. Ideally, it would look like in [these screenshots](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-check-jenkins-plugin#OWASPDependency-CheckPlugin-Screenshots), but plain old xUnit output would probably be fine as well.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I installed the [OWASP Dependency-Check](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-check-jenkins-plugin) Jenkins plugin, which sounds just right according to its documentation. But it seems I cannot figure out how to configure it properly.

I also tried archiving the XML file like regular Junit results from my Jenkinsfile, using `junit '**/target/security-reports/*.xml'`. But the Junit step doesn't seem to recognise it and complains about not finding any reports.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

To make Jenkins collect and display results of OWASP Dependency-check you need to have OWASP Dependency-Check plugin installed and to add Post-build Action step "Publish OWASP Dependency-Check analysis results".

You should provide the path to your XML file in settings for this step, by default `**/dependency-check-report.xml` is used.